# If one item is selected in listview

Tags: delphi, listview, selected

How can i see if exactly one item is selected in a listview?

I now use:

```
if listview1.Selected <> nil then
begin
...
end;
```

But this code works when one or more items are selected, what is the script to see if one item is selected

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
if ListView1.SelCount = 1 then
  // do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide any info on Delphi version, VCL or FireMonkey... so I'm not sure this will work in all cases:

```
If ListView1.Selected = ListView1.Items[IndexOfItemYouWantToCheck]
```

or, if you have a reference to the item in some variable, then:

```
If ListView1.Selected = ItemYouWantToCheck
```